# Aurelia - Value input depend on another input

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have 2 inputs like this:

**HTML**

```
<template>
  Input1
  <textarea name="" value.bind="item.input1" placeholder=""></textarea>

  Input2
  <textarea name="" value.bind="item.input2" placeholder=""></textarea>
</template>
```

**TS FILE**

```
import { MyModel } from '../models/mymodel';
export class MyApp {
    constructor() {
    }

    item: MyModel;

    activate(dto: MyModel) {
        this.item = new MyModel();

    }

}
```

I want that when I type text in `Input1`, `Input2` will bind to the value from `Input1`, but when I delete text in `Input1`, the value in `Input2` will not change.

**For example:**

I type `Hello World` in `Input1` *=>* `Input2` value will be: `Hello World`.

If I change the `Input1` value to: `Hello` *=>* `Input2` value will still be: `Hello World`

Comment: Btw, I'd recommend removing unnecessary details from your question. Things like your bootstrap classes or the multiple divs in your html are distracting from the actual issue. Try to create a _minimal_ example showcasing the problem (in your case, two textareas and a simple viewmodel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `observe` your first input for changes and update the other input if the value got changed to something longer like this:

```
import { observable } from "aurelia-binding";

export class MyModel {
  @observable()
  public input1: string;
  public input2: string;

  public input1Changed(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (!oldValue || (newValue && newValue.length > oldValue.length)) {
      this.input2 = newValue;
    }
  }
}
```

Using the `observable` decorator, and a convention-named method `input1Changed` (`[property]Changed`), you can listen for changes and use the old and new values as you please.

Comment: Jesse, if we want to watch for change on an object for instance on `item = {    input1 : '',    input2 : ''  }`. How would we do that? I have created plunker link for this: https://plnkr.co/edit/tOXmfo?p=preview

Comment: @Ray You can use the `bindingEngine` for this: https://plnkr.co/edit/9w8MBv8Y7yeMCgwcdeWw?p=preview (I'm new to plunker let me know if this link is correct)

Comment: you did it right. :) Thanks for providing the great example.